# SOS: my SOLR prod server is crashing every 30 minutes

Tags: tomcat, solr

UPDATE: SEE [Sunspot-Solr slowing down to a beast once my Application climbed to > 1000 objects [ Solr Logs Included ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887142/sunspot-solr-slowing-down-to-a-beast-once-my-application-climbed-to-1000-objec)

SysAdmin has identified a spike in Xen CPU interrupts, Have no idea what could cause this.   Xen virq_timer interrupts spike about 10 minutes before a crash, this is how we are identifying a crash is coming or not.

As soon as the xen cpu interrupts spikes 10 minutes following the spike tomcat dies.

Running plain value setup up.  It is indexing blogpost type content.  Here is the error I see repeatedly:

SEVERE: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ExactPhraseScorer.(ExactPhraseScorer.java:37)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.PhraseQuery$PhraseWeight.scorer(PhraseQuery.java:251)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanQuery.java:298)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.FilteredQuery.getFilteredScorer(FilteredQuery.java:149)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:577)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:364)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1296)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1176)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:375)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:394)

SEVERE: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2894)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:117)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:407)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:241)
    at java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format(SimpleFormatter.java:88)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.publish(FileHandler.java:198)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:476)
    at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:588)
    at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.info(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:285)

### at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1386)

```
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

May 16, 2013 1:04:46 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ExactPhraseScorer.(ExactPhraseScorer.java:38)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.PhraseQuery$PhraseWeight.scorer(PhraseQuery.java:251)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanQuery.java:298)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.FilteredQuery.getFilteredScorer(FilteredQuery.java:149)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:577)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:364)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1296)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1176)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:375)

### at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:394)

Settings:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m"
```

Comment: You are simply running out of heap space. What is your [`-Xmx` setting](http://serverfault.com/questions/139435/where-to-set-java-heap-options-e-g-xmx-for-tomcat-6-under-ubuntu-9-04)?

Comment: Added settings, see above.

Comment: And what is your number of documents you keep in Solr?

Comment: 2000 docs. A sneaky suspicion my team has is the number of terms I am sending off to solr.  I have seen upto 95 to 106 terms in a post to the solr sever.  Cannot prove it but that is what my team thinks is the offender.

Comment: Here was the solution to this issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887142/sunspot-solr-slowing-down-to-a-beast-once-my-application-climbed-to-1000-objec

Answer (score 0):

It may also be that you are sending different kind of queries to the server now, ones that require more memory to process. Java doesn't allocate memory on demand, instead it takes what is given for it when application is started and if it runs out then it simply crashes with the OutOfMemoryError. Application may run fine until the index sizes grow and queries consume enough memory to cause problems.

The default Java heap size settings (256Mb?) are very low to run Solr with. In my experience 1-2Gb is useful minimum or Solr will keel over constantly. You can observe the Solr memory usage from the admin interface and adjust your settings accordingly to match the memory requirements of your particular index/query types.

You can increase the memory allocation by giving Solr -Xmx1024m parameter on startup, or by adding that setting to the JAVA_OPTS environment variable for all java applications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Fuu, I added the settings info above.